What is the purpose of で in 他のチームのヘルプでやってるだけだから?
In the start of season 2 of New Game, a couple members of the character design team is questioning why their team leader Yagami has stayed at the office last night.

A: 八神さん､ 泊まりやったんですか


B: 今そんなに忙しくないでしょう? 他のチームのヘルプでやってるだけだから

The company has just released their latest game and the character team has little work to do while the executives finalize the next project, so I believe the meaning of "他のチームのヘルプでやってるだけだから" is like "all we're doing right now is helping other teams". In that case, I would expect not で but を to be used, like "他のチームのヘルプをやってるだけだから". I know で can describe the way or action an action is carried out, like 元気で居てほしい and 列車で来た, and those feels different to me than the sentence in the dialog since "他のチームのヘルプでやってるだけだから" seems just to be saying what they've been doing (helping the other teams).

This で is roughly the same as として or "as".

他のチームのヘルプでやってるだけだから。
Because she's doing it just as help for another team.

ヘルプをやってるだけだから also makes sense in this context, but で focuses more on her role (i.e., "just as a supporting member").

Thank you, I studied a bit and came to the same conclusion after asking a native speaker. I think much of my confusion came from ヘルプ and how I assumed it worked only in the sense of the English "to help" as in "He helped his grandfather clean the kitchen". As you point out, it has the meaning of help like an aid, supporting member, helping hand, etc.
